# Change CSV headers on export

Tags: powershell, csv

I have the following code,

```
Get-AdGroup -filter * | select Name, sAMAccountName | Foreach-Object{
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        oldAccount = $_.Name
        newAccount = "c:0-.t|adfs-2|" + $_.sAMAccountName

    }
} | Export-CSV "ADGroups.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

This works as designed and everything comes out as it should but they do not comeout in the order I need. I believe they come out in alphabetical order so the newAccount is always first. How can I make newAccount the second column?

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: Major version 2 minor version 0 build and revision are both -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a Select-Object prior to the export, that will define the order.

```
Get-AdGroup -filter * | select Name, sAMAccountName | Foreach-Object{
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        oldAccount = $_.Name
        newAccount = "c:0-.t|adfs-2|" + $_.sAMAccountName
    }
} | select oldAccount, newAccount | Export-CSV "ADGroups.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could write your own CSV

```
"`"oldAccount`",`"newAccount`"" | Out-File "ADGroups.csv" 
Get-AdGroup -filter * | select Name, sAMAccountName | Foreach-Object{
    "`"$_.Name`",c:0-.t|adfs-2|$_.sAMAccountName" | Out-File "ADGroups.csv" -append        
}
```